# Registry Startup Entry with runas argument?

Tags: python, windows, registry, startup, runas

Is it possible to add a startup entry in the windows registry with a runas argument? So when it launches, it runs with the user specified?

Comment: This seems like more of a question for superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this recipe:

- [Reading from and writing to the Windows Registry (Python)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66011-reading-from-and-writing-to-the-windows-registry/)

It has python code to read from the registry to show which applications run at start as well as to write a new entry to launch a windows explorer at startup

Comment: How do I give my script privileges to edit the Run key? I get an exception when I try to do so.